# How can I composite images whose sizes exceed Safari's canvas size limit (2^24 pixels) side-by-side?

Tags: javascript, frontend, image-manipulation

In my vuejs app, I have a need to composite multiple images (available as base64 png sources) into a single one. For all other browsers, my current approach of using `canvas`'s `drawImage` and `toDataURL` works fine, but [mobile] Safari has a `canvas` size limitation of 16 777 216 pixels. Unfortunately, for other reasons, the images cannot be resized to fit this limit.

I have looked at `merge-images` (uses `canvas` under the hood), and even tried supplying `node-canvas` as an alternate `canvas` implementation to it before I realized `node-canvas` just uses the plain old html5 `canvas` if used in the browser.

The requirements for a solution are:

- support for merging png images, supplied as base64 `img`-compatible sources, with adjustable relative positions
- maximum dimensions of the composited image being over 10 000 px per side
- support for transparency

Is there any library that could do this in the frontend?

Comment: Tricky. Any solution is also going to have to work within the browser's memory limit, so an uncompressed RGBA image of 10000 * 10000 px * 4 bytes/px = 400 MB is probably out of the question on some browser/platform or another. You could show a lower resolution preview in the browser and do the full compositing on the backend.

Comment: Areas to consider that come to mind for me include letting something written in Web Assembly do the heavy lifting, shipping the images to a server somewhere to do the heavy lifting (might be too slow and costly), or the classic "hey user, use another browser" type of message, when you do have images that are too big.

Comment: Could also consider using more than one canvas, then either showing them side by side, or downsampling the images from the first canvases and repainting them at a smaller scale on the main presenter canvas.

Comment: Asking for a library recommendation is off-topic, but there are many [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcanvas%5D+%5Bjavascript%5D+size+limitation) on SO that might provide an appropriate solution.